# Clarification of Web API in WebForm

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have created Web API.I know the Main advantage of Web API is cross domain application (I can call Web API in all platform). My question is ,Is there any performance issue When I call Web API in ASP.net WebForm???

I would like to know the below scenario

1.I Can use Direct SQL Query in .aspx Page 
2.I Can use Web API and generate JSON to DataTable

I would like to know which one is fast and better to use.......

I have tried in JQuery,the performance is fine but I would like to call in ASP.net WEb Form

Answer (score 1):

Where you call the API from or from what type of app makes no difference. Your issues are going to come from how you use it and what you do with the results of the calls.

Yes, you can get JSON data from the API and yes you can convert that to a DataTable, technically no issue there, but the performance will depend on how much data you retrieve in one go and how many transformations you go through to get it to the state you need for your webforms controls.

You're talking about using a dead tech ( webforms ) and trying to fit some things into how that works, which while possible, is not really the way to build anything these days.

SQL in aspx kinda says it all.Assuming you have an old app, that you just do updates to then just do what you can, but I would start looking into modern ways of building web apps. You don't have to keep using webforms controls anymore.

You can't talk about scalability when you still have stuff thrown in aspx pages. You need to start thinking about a proper separation of concerns, think about testing your stuff, retrieving only the data you need etc etc. Just because you add WebApi in the mix, that doesn't mean you'll get all the benefits, if everything else does not catch up to the required standard.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inherent performance issue with using WebAPI, aside from the overhead of an additional network hop.

In real world terms, I think this would be negligible and outweighed by the benefits:

- You get the 'cross platform' benefit you mentioned.
- Better scalability as your 'service' and 'web' concerns are seperated and can be scaled  appropriate to the load they need to serve.
- The service layer functionality is re-useable, for example if you wanted to develop an app later.